# AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService Nifi : Assume Role ARN not working as expected

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-nifi

I am using Apache Nifi(version nifi-1.22.0) to call AWS API (using InvokeAWSGatewayApi).

My processor looks like below:

[image: InvokeAWSGatewayApi processor]

[image: AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService configuration]

There is no problem in copying the credential, still I am getting unauthorized error message. Can you please point where I am doing wrong.

**aws.gateway.api.response.body**

`AuthFailure`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials574d5030-d062-4e59-a7b8-e6210d4f3557

**aws.gateway.api.status.code**
401

**aws.gateway.api.status.message**
Unauthorized

Thanks,
Priyanka